# When does one quadratic form divide another?

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $Q_1, Q_2$ be two quadratic forms with integer coefficients in 4 variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$, both non-singular and not proportional. For a positive number $X$, which we may assume to be large compared to the heights of the $Q_i$’s, how does one estimate the size of the set of all $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb{Z}^4$ for which
\begin{gather*}
\max\{\lvert x_1\rvert, \lvert x_2\rvert, \lvert x_3\rvert, \lvert x_4\rvert\} \leq X \\
\text{and} \\
Q_1(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \text{ divides } Q_2(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)?
\end{gather*}

Comment: Is $Q_1$ definite or indefinite?  (For $Q_2$ it's less of an issue, because the question for $Q_2 - c Q_1$ is equivalent to the one for $Q_2$ and might have a different signature.)

Comment: At least for me, it was hard to see what this question had to do about divisibility, since the condition on the values of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ was way off to the right.  I edited to make it more prominent, hopefully without disturbing meaning.  Please feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: (Also, the title seems quite different from the actual question, which seems to be more like "how often do the values of one quadratic form divide the values of another?")

Comment: Why starting with $4$ variables? What can be said about e.g. quadratic forms of $2$ variables?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies in my question one cannot assume that $Q_1$ is definite.

Comment: @LSpice I liked your edit, and I made a further refinement.

Comment: In the $Q_1$ definite case, it seems that $Q_2 -  c Q_1 =0 $ has solutions for only finitely many $c$, and we can solve one $c$ at a time, which is just a single quadratic form in four variables. I think estimating the number of solutions by the circle method is a classically solved problem. So in fact we may assume $Q_1$ indefinite. I think the number of solutions to the previous problem provides a lower bound, but should maybe be off by a log factor because of the sum over $c$ (just thinking heuristically).

Comment: Maybe one can try the (Kloosterman?) circle method for the full problem but I am not optimistic.